# Why is comparing double faster than uint64?

Tags: performance, matlab, integer, compare, double

I analysed the following program using Matlab's `profile`. Both double and uint64 are 64-bit variables. Why is comparing two double much faster than comparing two uint64? Aren't they both compared bitwise?

```
big = 1000000;

a = uint64(randi(100,big,1));
b = uint64(randi(100,big,1));
c = uint64(zeros(big,1));
tic;
for i=1:big
    if a(i) == b(i)
        c(i) = c(i) + 1;
    end
end
toc;

a = randi(100,big,1);
b = randi(100,big,1);
c = zeros(big,1);
tic;
for i=1:big
    if a(i) == b(i)
        c(i) = c(i) + 1;
    end
end
toc;
```

This is the measurement of profile:

[image: profile screenshot]

This is what tictoc measures:

```
Elapsed time is 6.259040 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.015387 seconds.
```

The effect disappears when uint8..uint32 or int8..int32 are used instead of 64-bit data types.

Comment: I don't know about Matlab, but frequently doubles are compared to see if they are within a distance epsilon of each other.  That makes the comparison more cumbersome.

Comment: @EricJ. Not the case in matlab, I'm afraid.  Also a bit confused by this question.

Comment: from your results it looks like comparing doubles is much faster than uint64

Comment: Octave reports 3s and 2.9s, respectively.

Comment: @jonas you are right. This is even more confusing to me.
Eric: ((2e-16)+1 == 1) is false in Matlab and this is at the edge of the precision double can achieve.

Comment: *Aren't they both compared bitwise?* No, can't do that for `double`s. For [IEEE 754 doubles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision), `0` and `-0` have different binary representations, but must compare equal when tested for equality. OTOH, two `NaN`s will have identical binary representations, but must always compare not equal to each other.

Comment: Interesting. What version of Matlab and what operating system are you running? Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: @Stein: `2e-16` is near the limit of relative precision for `double` at 1, but not exactly; it's just a rule of thumb. Use `eps(1)` to see exactly what the precision limit is. E.g. `(eps(1)/3) + 1 == 1` should be true.

Comment: It's possible that floating-point operations can occur in parallel with integer and flow-control operations, but I think something else is at work here. The difference is too great.

Comment: It is reproducible for `single`, `uint8,16,32` and `int8,16,32,64`, so basically anything *except* `double`...

Comment: cancel that; I'm on an APU which messes things up. It is no longer reproducible when I test it on 64-bit CPU with 64-bit Matlab R2012.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably a combination of the Matlab interpreter and the underlying CPU not supporting 64-bit int types as well as the others.

Matlab favors `double` over `int` operations. Most values are stored in `double` types, even if they represent integer values. The `double` and `int` `==` operations will take different code paths, and MathWorks will have spent a lot more attention on tuning and optimizing the code for `double` than for ints, especially `int64`. In fact, older versions of Matlab did not support arithmetic operations on `int64` at all. (And IIRC, it still doesn't support mixed-integer math.) When you do `int64` math, you're using less mature, less tuned code, and the same may apply to `==`. Int types are not a priority in Matlab. The presence of the `int64` may even interfere with the JIT optimizing that code, but that's just a guess.

But there might be an underlying hardware reason for this too. Here's a hypothesis: if you're on 32-bit x86, you're working with 32-bit general purpose (integer) registers. That means the smaller int types can fit in a register and be compared using fast instructions, but the 64-bit int values won't fit in a register, and may take more expensive instruction sequences to compare. The `double`s, even though they are 64 bits wide, will fit in the wide floating-point registers of the x87 floating point unit, and can be compared in hardware using fast floating-point comparison instructions. This means the `[u]int64`s are the only ones that can't be compared using fast single-register, single-instruction operations.

If that's the case, if you run this same code on 64-bit x86-64 (in 64-bit Matlab), the difference may disappear because you then have 64-bit wide general purpose registers. But then again, it may not, if the Matlab interpreter's code isn't compiled to take advantage of it.

Comment: +1, seems the hardware is mostly at fault here. I tested on R2010 on an APU (which has fast double precision arithmetic but horrible integer math), and the problem was identical for `single` and `(u)int8,16,33`.  Then I tested on 64-bit CPU, 64-bit R2012 Matlab (which has 64-bit wide general purpose registers), and all problems disappeared.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis: Ooh, tell us more about this APU you're running on. That sounds interesting and is new to me.

Comment: See [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Accelerated_Processing_Unit_microprocessors); I have an AMD A6-3650, mostly thanks to the fetishes of our IT manager ;) So far however, it's not been very good to me; there's lots of strange side effects (like the one I mentioned earlier). For the high-performance scientific computations/simulations I'm doing/designing, I prefer CPU+GPU for now :) Granted, my APU is rather new and not really the best out there, so I hope this will change in the future (because I do believe they have a lot of potential)

Comment: I'm seeing a noticeable slowdown using uint64 over double, like 3-4 x slower. I need to do more work to make sure, but I'm running 64 bit windows on a new i9 CPU and really thought uint64 would not be the problem it is turning out to be. I need to convert my variables to double to verify, which I'm going to do shortly. I'm trying to gulp down 32 GB of data and do some simple compares with them while in memory. This is really interesting.